# You must use HTTPS while generating Kong client credentials

Tags: docker, rhel7, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

Can anyone please help me out. I'm getting error while generating KONG client credentials on HTTP port 8000.

```
{
    "error_description": "You must use HTTPS",
    "error": "access_denied"
}
```

I have added trusted_ips = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0 in kong.conf also, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you used Load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it over https(using port 8443 instead of 8000).If youre using localhost Do something like:

```
curl -X POST \
--url "https://127.0.0.1:8443/<route name>/oauth2/token " \
  --header "Host: <route host>" \
  --data "grant_type=password" \
  --data "client_id=<clientid>" \
  --data "client_secret=<clientsecret>" \
  --data "provision_key=<provision_key>"\
  --data "redirect_uri=http://localhost/cb/" \
  --data "authenticated_userid=<userid>"  \
  --insecure
```

you can follow this [link](https://github.com/Kong/kong-oauth2-hello-world) for further details on how to go about this